# Argonaut - Returning an error in a custom decoder

Tags: json, scala, error-handling, argonaut

I'm trying to implement an Argonaut JSON decoder instance that converts JSON strings to instances of my enum `QuestionType`. The problem is that if the string isn't a valid, the returned DecodeResult should be an error, and I'm not sure how to do that.

My code currently looks like this:

```scala
implicit def QuestionTypeDecodeJson: DecodeJson[QuestionType] = {
    DecodeJson(c => for {
      typeName <- c.as[String]
      questionType = QuestionType.fromString(typeName).get
    } yield questionType)
  }
```

`QuestionType.fromString(typeName)` returns an `Option`. Ideally, instead of using `get`, I would like to convert the `Option` to a `DecodeResult`, with either the contents of the Option, or an error state if it's `None`.

I could use the constructor of `DecodeResult`, but to be honest the signature of that is quite confusing to me (I'm new to scala). It seems that it requires a `CursorHistory` object, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to pass in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DecodeResult object has an 'ok' and a 'fail' method.

```
implicit def QuestionTypeDecodeJson: DecodeJson[QuestionType] = {
    DecodeJson(c => for {
      typeName <- c.as[String]
      questionType = DecodeResult.ok(QuestionType.fromString(typeName))
    } yield questionType)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you had to go to a separate page in the scaladocs to see the "static functions" (functions in the object of the same name).